# Cross chain call contract on ethereum from private network

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, tokens, private-blockchain, golang

Im looking for a way to call a contract that is deployed on the ethereum main network using Go (or JS/anything).
From what i can see the foolproof way is to do so over json RPC but i would love to hear of gracefull solutions if 
anyone has them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example of how to query a smart contract using Go and the go-ethereum package.

MyContract.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract MyContract {
  string public foo;

  constructor() public {
    foo = "bar";
  }
}
```

Compilation

```
solc --abi MyContract.sol | awk '/JSON ABI/{x=1;next}x' > MyContract.abi
solc --bin MyContract.sol | awk '/Binary:/{x=1;next}x' > MyContract.bin
abigen --bin=MyContract.bin --abi=MyContract.abi --pkg=store --out=MyContract.go
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"

    store "./contracts" // for demo
)

func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    address := common.HexToAddress("0x147B8eb97fD247D06C4006D269c90C1908Fb5D54")
    instance, err := store.NewMyContract(address, client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    version, err := instance.Foo(nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(foo) // "bar"
}
```